# Ubuntu 13.10 time sync issues with VMware Player

Tags: vmware-player

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 (64 bit) on VM Player on Windows 7 Host. Everything is running fine except that my time is out of sync. I have set the correct timezone and everything. But for some strange reason, The time is out of sync.

Comment: What is your host OS?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. Windows 7

Comment: Try installing [VMWare tools](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1035392).

Comment: Installed Everything. Nothing works!

Comment: After installing VMWare tools, make sure you enable timesync by running:`vmware-toolbox-cmd timesync enable` in terminal.  Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable this feature in your vm settings. Click on vm, choose "edit vm settings", "options", "vmware tools", and check the box for "sync guest time with host time."

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem and this didn't help. I also tried `vmware-toolbox-cmd timesync enable` and it didn't help ither.